# ShareLatex Compiling issue with standalone package

Tags: tikz-pgf, standalone

I am having issues with Sharelatex not compiling my standalone Tikz pictures. For my standalone Tikz pictures, I am graphing by referencing .csv files as shown.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[   
%width=11cm,
%height=7cm,
xlabel={Displacement [\si{\milli\meter}]}, 
ylabel={Shear Stress [\si{\kilo\newton\per\meter\squared}]}, 
ymin=0,
xmin=0,
legend pos= south east
]

\addplot+ [smooth,mark=none,color=blue] table [x=Scherweg, y=Scherspannung, col sep=comma] {../Data/ShearTest/ExportedData/Test7.csv};

\addlegendentry{\footnotesize \SI{100}{\kilo\newton\per\meter\squared} Normal Stress}


\addplot+ [dashed,mark=none,color=red] table [x=Scherweg, y=Scherspannung, col sep=comma] {../Data/ShearTest/ExportedData/Test8.csv};

\addlegendentry{\footnotesize \SI{75}{\kilo\newton\per\meter\squared} Normal Stress}

\addplot+ [thick,dotted,mark=none,color=green] table [x=Scherweg, y=Scherspannung, col sep=comma] {../Data/ShearTest/ExportedData/Test9.csv};

\addlegendentry{\footnotesize \SI{50}{\kilo\newton\per\meter\squared} Normal Stress}


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

These compile perfectly fine as standalones. However, once I reference the file in my main .tex document, the graph shows up blank.
[image: Example of blank graph in main .tex document]

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Comment: what is the warning message? Probably your path is wrong

Comment: Package pgfplots Error: Could not read table file '../Data/ShearTest/ExportedData/Test7.csv' in 'search path=.'. In case you intended to provide inline data: maybe TeX screwed up your end-of-lines? Try `row sep=crcr' and terminate your lines with `\\' (refer to the pgfplotstable manual for details).

Comment: Did you? What happened next?

Comment: It then gives me a new error : "Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the choice 'row sep=crcr' is currently only available for inline tables, not for external files."  Should I be using the subfile package instead of standalone?